# What would be the UML relationship, between 2 classes which have the database id of the other, but do not have references to each other?

Tags: oop, orm, uml, associations, class-diagram

The classes would be plain objects, pojos in java, what would be the UML relation between them, or there would not be any, but they would be related to other classes that used them?.

[image: Diagram?]

Comment: Each realation gets 2 number, one at each end. The numbers answer the question: How many of the objects of the class near to number belong to one object of the class at the other end?
Also: Will the associate far object be deleted as well, if the near one is deleted?

Comment: My question is about the UML Class diagram not the ER, is there a relationship between those 2 clases? it certainly is not association since there is no physical relationship between the 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `invoice_id` foreign key means that there is a structural relation between `Invoice` and `InvoiceLine` . You would therefore represent it as an association in the class diagram. Multiplicity would be by deduction `1` on `Invoice` side `0..*` on `InvoiceLine` side.

The technique is a classic of ORM called "[foreign key mapping](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/foreignKeyMapping.html)" by some authors. Use of soft identifiers rather than object references is also quite common, especially in complex real-life domains,  to avoid having to load all the related objects when you fetch just one from the DB.

You may use the `{id}` modifier to document primary keys:

> A Property may be marked (...) as being (part of) the identifier (if any) for Classifiers of which it is a member. The interpretation of this is left open but this could be mapped to implementations such as primary keys for relational database tables or ID attributes in XML. 
> -UML 2.5.1 specifications

Comment: I see it on the ER where i would agree, but there will be no reference to an object of InvoiceLine in Invoice, nor of Invoice in InvoiceLine.
Would it still count as a asociación? i would think not.

Comment: The fact that you don't have the reference on entity level doesn't mean you have no reference at all. The foreign key is a reference.

Comment: @VaderSkywalker Indeed, I can only repeat what Ister just told. Nothing in the formal definition of an association requires an object reference to be used.  The use of such reference is an implementation choice that you can adopt, but do not have to.